# Includes() function alternative React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a function that checks if the link matches the path. Everything works when I'm running the local server, but on the build process it fails with the error "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined'. While i'm digging into the error, what's the best way to reformat this function without using includes()?

```
 matchLink = (link, path) => {

        return path.includes(link)
    };
```

Comment: The error is about the includes

Comment: If it works in development but not production, chances are it’s a build problem not a code problem

Comment: The error is about path, not includes.  `path` is undefined, thus does not have an includes method.

Comment: I understand :) That's why I'm asking what's the other best way to reformat this function that's efficient

Comment: when I console.log path it shows the path, the typeof path also confirms that it's a string

Comment: Initially you had said `indexOf` sorry.

Comment: That means there's probably something wrong with how you're passing path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking if `path` is `undefined` and return false if it is.

If you don't want to use `includes`, `indexOf` can work as well.

```
matchLink = (link, path) => {
  return !!path && path.indexOf(link) > -1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some more alternatives you can use

```js
const matchLink = (link, path) => {
  let reg = new RegExp(link)
  console.log('RegEx Method : ',  reg.test(path))
  console.log('Search Method : ', path.search(link)>-1)
};


matchLink("http://www.example.com","http://www.example.com/123")
matchLink("http://www.example123.com","http://www.example.com/123")
```